# Database design -- does it respect 3rd NF?

Tags: sql, database-design, database, relational

I have the following relations (tables) in a relational model

```
Person
  person_id, first_name, last_name, address

Student
  person_id, matr_nr

Teacher
  person_id, salary

Lecture
  lecture_id, lect_name, lect_description

Attendees
  lecture_id, person_id, date
```

I'm wondering about the functional dependencies of Student and Teacher.

Do these tables respect the 3rd normal form? Which should be the primary keys of these tables?

Comment: if a person is a student and a teacher (grad student) and they attend a lecture, how will you tell who is the real teacher of the lecture??

Comment: This sounds like homework from class.

Comment: Is this in the context of a single institution?  Because a student and/or instructor can be either of these roles at other institutions.

Comment: Good question. I see, it's not well normalized. How should I do it?

Comment: @william: it is a not a homework all by itself, it's something I'm asking myself on the way to solving the homework, which is much more complex. I'm looking for explanations, not for being spoon fed with a solution.

Comment: Flavius, without knowing what you're trying to solve (give the specs), it is difficult to recommend fixes, at some point you need to make assumptions, like is it one teacher per lecture or multiple, etc.

Comment: Whether a teacher can also be a student, etc. doesn't determine if the design is normalized. That's more a matter of, does your design implement your solution given a particular set of requirements. That's a little bit different than normalization - which is a set of guidelines that have been shown to (in general) promote a good design that avoids certain pitfalls in DB development.

Comment: @KM: grad students are not taken into account here. There are either students, or teachers (european university system). Of couse Students may become Teachers, but as they do, they get moved from Student to Teacher. After this point, when they attend a lecture, once can say with certainty which are the teachers and which are the students. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Flavius: So, a once someone becomes a teacher they're never allowed to attend a lecture that they are not themselves teaching? It's not uncommon for teachers to also take classes from other teachers - in which case they are also students.

Comment: if you have a FK from student to any work they did, do you DELETE that when they become a teacher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using concepts like "table inheritance" (loosely) and join tables I would set things up in this manner:

```
 Person
  person_id, first_name, last_name, address

Student
  student_id, person_id, matr_nr

Teacher
  teacher_id, person_id, salary

Lecture
  lecture_id, teacher_id, lect_name, lect_description, date

Attendees
  lecture_id, student_id
```

Where Student and Teacher tables "inherit" from Person and the Attendees table is a Join table between Lecture and Student (teacher_id is used in the Lecture table to specify who's teaching the class. And by Join table best practice the table ought actually be named Lecture_Student or similar)

**Alternate Design:** (allows for multiple teachers of a class)

```
Person
person_id, first_name, last_name, address

Student
student_id, person_id, matr_nr

Teacher
teacher_id, person_id, salary

Lecture
lecture_id, lect_name, lect_description, date

Lecture_Student
lecture_id, student_id

Lecture_Teacher
lecture_id, teacher_id
```

Comment: So the functional dependency of say Student would be (student_id,person_id) -> matr_nr? (i.e. the primary key would be a compound key?)

Comment: No. student_id would be the sole primary key. person_id would be a foreign key that links back to person and creates the "inheritance" relationship. Notice that person_id is not used anywhere else in the schema except as pkey in Person and foreign key in Student and Teacher.

Comment: The student_id and teacher_id seem pretty redundant to me. Also, this only allows for a single teacher to be involved in a lecture, which may or may not be the case. I'd probably put an "attendee_type" in the Attendees table instead.

Comment: To help you get your head around it: Imagine if you didn't have the Person table... you would simply used the first_name, last_name, address columns in both your Student and Teacher tables, which would be OK too. In the end it's somewhat arbitrary. Don't let the dependency on the Person table inform your design of the Lecture and Attendees tables... think of Teacher/Student at that point (that's what my proposed design does.)

Comment: @Paul thanks. I have a hard time grasping this, as I try to think too object-oriented.

Comment: Paul's design is somewhat object-oriented, too. Amongst other characteristics of his design, one person could be multiple students and one person could be multiple teachers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's 3NF normalized (the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key) as far as what we know, but it might not solve your problem domain issues.

Your primary keys would be the _id columns - except for attendees.  where it would be both _id columns - but this would not accommodate attending the same lecture on different dates (or would that technically be a different lecture_id?)  In a class scheduling system I built, we had sections in a class, but the problem domain for this could be much larger than what you have given.

The problem with students and teachers has already been raised - both will be attendees, that's about all you will know - all the teachers could be teaching or only some of them could be teaching, or they could be peers (seminar, say)

I think this is more of a domain modeling issue first, then normalization...

Answer (score 0):

"Do these tables respect the 3rd normal form?"

That question is only answerable if you tell us what the keys are and what the full set of functional dependencies is.

Without that, any answer anyone gives can only be the result of a nonzero amount of guesswork on the part of the answerer, and you have no guarantee that that guesswork corresponds to your business reality.

That said, you might look into the Attendees.  It's more than likely that there's something rotten there.

(Hey, you claimed yourself you didn't want to be spoonfed.)

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not 3NF. A simple, normalised design for the above problem (assuming that person_id uniquely identifies both teachers and students, and that there is one teacher per lecture) would be as follows:

```
Person
  person_id (PK), first_name, last_name, address, Student_matr_nr, Teacher_salary

Lecture
  lecture_id (PK), teacher_person_id (FK), lect_name, lect_description

Attendees
  lecture_id (PK), student_person_id (PK), date
```

Relations that have the same key as each other *are the same relation*.